# Compose Multiplatform: remove 'x' button in window title bar

Tags: kotlin, desktop-application, compose-multiplatform

I have a Dialog in my Compose Multiplatform app and a want to remove the close button in the window title bar. If I can, how do I remove this button?
For now, I've removed the button's behavior by using an empty function at onCloseRequest.

Reproducible example
(you can see 2 windows coming up. From the window on top, I want to remove the 'x' in the title bar):

```
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.window.*

fun main() {
    application {
        Window(
            onCloseRequest = ::exitApplication,
            title = "Desktop",
            //icon = BitmapPainter(image = imageBitmap),
            state = rememberWindowState(
                position = WindowPosition(Alignment.Center)
            ),
        ) {
            MaterialTheme() {
                // Dialog
                Dialog(
                    state = rememberDialogState(
                        position = WindowPosition(Alignment.Center),
                        width = 550.dp,
                        height = 500.dp
                    ),
                    title = "My Dialog",
                    onCloseRequest = {},
                ) {
                    // removed dialog content
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks and feel free to ask for any additional information :)

Comment: Swing (at least the tag in StackOverflow) is the Java library, using to create Desktop applications. But your code don't looks like Java. What a language you use? Please also add the corresponded language tag and provide a [mcve] so we can better understand your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I've added an example. I didn't use the Kotlin tag because the description of the tag said:  "Use this tag when you're having problems with the Kotlin language and standard...", so I thought because my problem didn't target the language or std lib, I shouldn't add it. (I've just read the full description)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way is to completely remove app bar

```
Window(
  //...
  undecorated = true,
  //...
)
```

> undecorated - Disables or enables decorations for this window.

Comment: Thanks! At least as for now...